# What is mean this convert?

Tags: c++, qt

I develop with QtFramework in c++. I encountered this converting method that is `static_cast<void (QTcpSocket::*)(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)>
(&QAbstractSocket::error)`. But I have not understand what is it  mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static_cast<void (QTcpSocket::*)(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)> (&QAbstractSocket::error)
```

where:

`&QAbstractSocket::error` - is the address of the function named `error(...)`;

And it is casting it to `void (QTcpSocket::*)(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)` - which is a pointer to a member (of QTcpSocket) function that takes a parameter `QAbstractSocket::SocketError` and returns `void`.

So we are casting from address of a function which is a member of QAbstractSocket (perhaps a base class) to a function pointer which is a member of QTcpSocket (perhaps the derived class).

**Note**

As talamaki explains really nicely the reason for this  (i.e. to pick the correct function during a connect(...); An alternative is to use the older Qt connect() style which you can explicitly choose the correct function at the cost of losing compiler-time errors if you get it wrong. I often think this is clearer (for example this question would probably not need to be asked). Here is an example:

```
// Here we can explicitly choose the correct function,
// and its clear to any reader what is going on.
connect(pTcpSocket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),
        this,       SLOT(errorHandler(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
```

Answer (score 2):

*QTcpSocket* inherits from the base class *QAbstractSocket*. There is a method `SocketError error()` and a signal `void error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError socketError)` in [QAbstractSocket](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#error), i.e. with the same name.

In the presence of overloads the address of the name of the function in itself is ambiguous. You can use `static_cast<>()` to specify which function to use according to the function signature implied by the function pointer type.

The cast in your question selects the signal because `void (QTcpSocket::*)(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)` is a pointer to a function type in QTcpSocket which returns `void` and takes a parameter `QAbstractSocket::SocketError`.

For example to connect to `QAbstractSocket::error` signal using the function pointer syntax, you must specify the signal type in a static cast.

Comment: Well said, sir. +1 for also pointing out the reason that one might do this, which also leads me to adding a note to my answer also (as a potential alternative)